# How to stream video from GridFS with Spring Webflux?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, gridfs

I want to get video from GridFS server and then stream it as .mp4 to user via REST endpoint. I am using Spring Webflux. As for now I have used code from some tutorial but the result isn't what I wanted. After sending GET request I get a page filled with weird symbols, instead of mp4 video. This is code for my logic:

```
public Flux<Void> read(@PathVariable String id, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    return this.reactiveGridFsTemplate.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("filename").is(id)))
            .flatMap(reactiveGridFsTemplate::getResource)
            .flatMapMany(r -> exchange.getResponse().writeWith(r.getDownloadStream()));
}
```

and for my controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/videos/{name}")
public Flux<?> getVideo(@PathVariable String name, ServerWebExchange exchange){
    return  gridStorageService.read(name, exchange);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at streamVideo method here - https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootMongoDBImageVideo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/springboot/mongodb/imagevideo/controller/VideoController.java

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `Content-Disposition` header in the response with the value attachment and the file name, so that the client can identify that it should be downloaded as a file, also set `produces` to `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)` or `"video/mp4"`.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/videos/{name}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<?> getVideo(@PathVariable String name, ServerWebExchange exchange){
    exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + name);
    return  gridStorageService.read(name, exchange);
}
```